# Dynamic range for filter function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have the following formula:

```
=iferror(sum(filter('November 2017'!$H:$H;'November 2017'!$D:$D=$B3)); 0)
```

Which I use to categorize expenses in a `Summary` sheet: `$B3` would be for example `Rent`, and this would pick all expenses in the `November 2017` sheet marked as `Rent`, and would compute the sum of it. This works fine.

But this is cumbersome: I have 20 expense categories that I am tracking, and now I want to create the corresponding entries for `December 2017`, which forces me to go through all the formulas and manually replace `November 2017` -> `December 2017`.

Is it possible to tell `filter` that the range of operation is specified in certain cell? This way I would just update that single cell (in the top of the December column for example), and all formula would use the right range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) within a query, say:

```
=query(indirect($B4&"!D:H");"select sum(H) where D ='"&B$3&"' label sum(H) ''")
```

but really you seem to have backed yourself into a corner. You appear to be trying to analyse data that has already been analysed. A more conventional solution may be to collect all the data together in one place (sheet) and then perform all the analysis from there, say with a pivot table.

B4 would hold `November 2017` (as text), B5 say `December 2017` and you would copy down the above formula (and across for other categories).

Comment: Not sure why you mean the data organization is not optimal: I have one sheet per month, for expenses, since I do not want to track all year expenses in a single huge sheet. And I have a summary sheet where I want to see exactly that, a summary per-category.